# Mapping, Addition and Interpolation with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Struggling through a basic Ruby challenge.  The objective is to take an array[1,2,3] and add 2 to each number.  The results should print out as a string such as:

```
["1 + 2 = 3", "2 + 2 = 4", "3 + 2 = 5"].
```

I know somehow, I need to differentiate between the two {num}s, but not sure how to go about this.

```
def add_two(array)

  array.map! { |num| num + 2 }
  array.map! { |num| num.to_s }
  array.map! { |num| "#{num} + 2 = #{num}" }

end
```

Returns:

```
["3 + 2 = 3", "4 + 2 = 4", "5 + 2 = 5"]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should it output "3 + 2 = 5", or should it put this string into the original array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do as :

```
[1,2,3].map { |a, ob = 2| "%d + %d = %d" % [a, ob, a + ob] }
# => ["1 + 2 = 3", "2 + 2 = 4", "3 + 2 = 5"]
```

Wrapped into a method :

```
def add_number_with_each_elem(array, number)
  array.map { |a| "%d + %d = %d" % [a, number, a + number] }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the answer recommended by the instructor, but both suggestions also worked too.

```
def add_two(array)
  array.map { |num| "#{num} + 2 = #{num+2}" }
end
```

Comment: hahaha.. Its same as me.. Once you accepted mine, people got to know.. which one you like most. You don't need to answer to let them know.. :p

Comment: IMO, this is more Ruby like.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map! do |num|
  puts "#{num} + 2 = #{num + 2}"

  num + 2
end
```

or with a temporary variable:

```
array.map! do |num|
  new_num = num + 2

  puts "#{num} + 2 = #{new_num}"

  new_num
end
```

For an array of `[1,2,3]`, both give you the result of `[3,4,5]` and output the strings along the way:

```
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 2 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
 => [3, 4, 5]
```

`map!` replaces each entry in `array` with the result of the last expression in your block. So if you run `array.map! { |num| "#{num} + 2 = #{num}" }`, you are not printing these strings, you are replacing the entries in your array with them.